# How do I parse a DumpBin.exe Output file with Regular Expression or LinqToText

Tags: c#, parsing, text, dumpbin

I'm writing a utility wrapper around dumpbin.exe and outputting exports and dependencies for exe files, ocx files and dllfiles. Besides dependency information, I also need to capture Export information such as if the file is self-registering.  Would anyone have knowledge on doing something like this?

Here is a sample output file:
Note: The Deserialize, DoServiceCall and Serialize lines below appear to he wrapping.
Bolded areas are the parts I need to capture.

### Also I've noticed in some reports the dependencies section can appear either above or below the exports.

Dump of file Secadmin.dll

File Type: DLL

**Image has the following dependencies:
    A1Mgr.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    USER32.dll
    ADVAPI32.dll
    ole32.dll
    OLEAUT32.dll**

Section contains the following exports for SecAdmin.dll

```
00000000 characteristics
3C4DD9F4 time date stamp Tue Jan 22 16:30:28 2002
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
       7 number of functions
       7 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      5    0 000153E0 ?Deserialize@CSecTuxClient@@AAEPATas_SecurityFunctions@@PAUtagSAFEARRAY@@PA_N@Z
      6    1 00015843 ?DoServiceCall@CSecTuxClient@@IAEPATas_SecurityFunctions@@PAT2@PAH@Z
      7    2 00014805 ?Serialize@CSecTuxClient@@AAEPAUtagSAFEARRAY@@PATas_SecurityFunctions@@H@Z
      1    3 0000CDA3 DllCanUnloadNow
      2    4 0000CDB8 DllGetClassObject
      3    5 0000CDD5 **DllRegisterServer**
      4    6 0000CE58 DllUnregisterServer
```

Summary

```
   29000 .data
    6000 .rdata
    4000 .reloc
    8000 .rsrc
   3B000 .text
```

Comment: what are you looking for? I can write some RegEx if you tell me where information is hiding.